# how to get the latest database collection from MongoDB with Mongo Engine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am very new to MongoDB. I create a database within a loop. Each time (Every 2 hours), I get data from some sources and create a data collection by MongoEngine and name each collection based on the creation time (for example 05_01_2021_17_00_30).
Now, on another python code , I want to get the latest database. how can I call the latest database collection without knowing the name of it?
I saw some guidelines in Stackoverflow but codes are old and not working now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Maybe better is to change those collection names to something easy to sort like: 20210105_170030  , so after you get the collection list with db.getCollectionNames()  you may easy sort and get the last element , but also to avoid too big list of collections maybe devide the collections per databases with names "20210105" so they contain only daily data ...

Comment: Thanks @kiko075. Actually, the naming system you proposed is a good idea. Also, it gave me an idea to use text file that contain the name of the last database that was created. Each time a new database is created, I write the name in a text file and grab it when needed. Does it look professional?

Comment: If you fix as proposed , you can get the last created from the mongo shell as follow:  var x=db.getCollectionNames().sort().slice(-1)[0];print(x)

Comment: Yeah, yours is more straight forward. thanks again.

Comment: almost same way you can do for the database names:  var ar=[];db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 , nameOnly : true} ).databases.forEach(function(d){ ar.push(d.name) }); var max=ar.sort().slice(-1)[0];print(max);

Comment: I just saw that you fetch data every 2h so maybe your collection may have shorter name like 20210105_1700 and your databases can hold data per month with the name 202101  , but afcourse entirely depends on how much data you insert ...

Comment: Thanks I got your point. I just have to figure it out in python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this answer:
In mongo_setup.py: when I want to create a database, it will be named after the time of creation and save the name in a text file.

```
import mongoengine
import datetime


def global_init():
    nownow = datetime.datetime.now()
    Update_file_name = str(nownow.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S"))
    # For Shaking hand between Django and the last updated data base, export the name 
          of the latest database
    # in a text file and from there, Django will understand which database is the 
           latest
    Updated_txt = open('.\\Latest database to read for Django.txt', '+w')
    Updated_txt.write(Update_file_name)
    Updated_txt.close()

    mongoengine.register_connection(alias='core', name=Update_file_name)
```

In Django views.py: we will call the text file and read the latest database's name:

```
database_name_text_file = 'directory of the text file...'
db_name_file = open(database_name_text_file, 'r')
db_name = db_name_file.read()
# MongoDb Database
myclient = MongoClient(port=27017)
mydatabase = myclient[db_name]
classagg = mydatabase['aggregation__class']
database_text = classagg.find()

for i in database_text:
     ....
```